# Can't write webpack loader using es6 imports

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, node-modules, webpack-loader

I wrote this webpack loader

```
module.exports = function(source) {
    return `export default 'hello'`;
}
```

that I want to rewrite using es6 imports

```
export default function loader(source) {
    return `export default 'hello'`;
}
```

without success

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

---

My webpack configuration is:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },,
    resolveLoader: {
        modules: [
            'node_modules',
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'loaders')
        ]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.m?js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                }
            }
        }, {
            test: /\.txt$/,
            use: {
                loader: 'my-loader'
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

How can I do this?

Comment: you can't because webpack will work on node js, which uses common js, es modules are not allowed on node yet.

Comment: So [this](https://webpack.js.org/contribute/writing-a-loader/#loader-utilities) example where the loader eses es6 imports can't work without pre-compiling it?

Comment: Nop, it won't work unless compiled.

Comment: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin as example... build using es6 but has a build step.

Comment: That's clear, thank you!